# Big O of this code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am doing the exercise of Skiena's book on algorithms and I am stuck in this question:

I need to calculate the big O of the following algorithm:

```
      function mystery()
      r=0
      for i=1 to n-1 do
         for j=i+1 to n do
            for k=1 to j do
                r=r+1
```

Here, the big O of the outermost loop will be O(n-1) and the middle loop will be O(n!). Please tell me if I am wrong here.

I am not able to calculate the big O of the innermost loop.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: It's hard to make a loop take a factorial time. This loop certainly does not do it. Did you misplace the exclamation point?

Comment: Before everyone rushes to answer why don't you say why you have those answer for the loops?

Comment: Obviously I calculated those answers. Well yes I may be wrong. Let me explain: Since the outer loop will run n-1 times so the linear complexity will be O(n-1) which is equivalent to O(n). In case of the middle loop, the loop will run from 2 to n, each time the base value will ve 3,4,5 and so on...so I think it will be n!. This is how I came to this.

Comment: Sorry the middle loop's big O will be O(n(n+1)/2-1). I multiplied previously and got n!. I must have added it. I am new to this so I need help.

Comment: n! is n * (n-1) * (n-2) ... Not n + (n-1) + (n-2) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more rigorous way to approach solving this problem:

Define the run-time of the algorithm to be `f(n)` since `n` is our only input. The outer loop tells us this

```
f(n) = Sum(g(i,n), 1, n-1)
```

where `Sum(expression, min, max)` is the sum of `expression` from `i = min` to `i = max`. Notice that, the expression in this case is an evaluation of `g(i, n)` with a fixed `i` (the summation index) and `n` (the input to `f(n)`). And we can peel another layer and define`g(i, n)`:

```
g(i, n) = Sum(h(j), i+1, n), where i < n
```

which is the sum of `h(j)` where `j` ranges of `i+1` to `n`. Finally we can just define

```
h(j) = Sum(O(1), 1, j)
```

since we've assumed that `r = r+1` takes time `O(1)`.

Notice at this point that we haven't done any hand-waving, saying stuff like "oh you can just multiply the loops together. The 'innermost operation' is the only one that counts." That statement isn't even *true* for all algorithms. Here's an example:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        Solve_An_NP_Complete_Problem(n);
        for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

The above algorithm isn't `O(n^3)`... it's not even polynomial.

Anyways, now that I've established the superiority of a rigorous evaluation (:D) we need to work our way upwards so we can figure out what the upper bound is for `f(n)`. First, it's easy to see that `h(j)` is `O(j)` (just use the definition of Big-Oh). From that we can now rewrite `g(i, n)` as:

```
g(i, n) = Sum(O(j), i+1, n)
=> g(i, n) = O(i+1) + O(i+2) + ... O(n-1) + O(n)
=> g(i, n) = O(n^2 - i^2 - 2i - 1) (because we can sum Big-Oh functions 
                                    in this way using lemmas based on 
                                    the definition of Big-Oh) 
=> g(i, n) = O(n^2) (because g(i, n) is only defined for i < n. Also, note
                     that before this step we had a Theta bound, which is 
                     stronger!)
```

And so we can rewrite `f(n)` as:

```
f(n) = Sum(O(n^2), 1, n-1)
=> f(n) = (n-1)*O(n^2) 
=> f(n) = O(n^3)
```

You might consider proving the lower bound to show that `f(n) = Theta(n^3)`. The trick there is note simplifying `g(i, n) = O(n^2)` but keeping the tight bound when computing `f(n)`. It requires some ugly algebra, but I'm pretty sure (i.e. I haven't actually done it) that you will be able to prove `f(n) = Omega(n^3)` as well (or just `Theta(n^3)` directly if you're really meticulous).

Answer (score 2):

The analysis takes place as follows:

- the outer loop goes from `i = [1, n - 1]`, so the program would have linear complexity  `O(i) = O(n)` if, inside this loop, only constant operations were performed;
- however, inside the first loop, for each `i`, some operation is executed `n` times -- starting from `j = [i + 1, n - 1]`. This gives a total complexity of `O(i * j) = O(n * n) = O(n^2)`;
- finally, the innermost loop will be executed, for each `i`, and for each `j`, `k` times, with `k` ranging from `k = [j, n - 1]`. As `j` begins with `i + 1 = 1 + 1`, `k` is assymptotically equal to `n`, which gives you `O(i * j * k) = O(n * n * n) = O(n^3)`.

The complexity of the program itself corresponds to the number of iterations of your innermost operations -- or the sums of complexities of innermost operations. If you had:

```
for i = 1:n

    for j = 1:n

        --> innermost operation (executed n^2 times)

        for k = 1:n
            --> innermost operation (executed n^3 times)
        endfor

        for l = 1:n
            --> innermost operation (executed n^3 times)
        endfor

    endfor

endfor
```

The total complexity would be given as `O(n^2) + O(n^3) + O(n^3)`, which is equal to `max(O(n^2), O(n^3), O(n^3))`, or `O(n^3)`.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be factorial. For example if u have two nested cycles the big O will be n^2, not n^n. So three cycles cannot give more than n^3. Keep digging ;)

Comment: Yes, it will be O(n^3).This is a general assumption that for three nested loops the Big O will be O(n^3). Since, I am a beginner, I want to understand how that general assumption has come. But I am not able to calculate it correctly, So here my calculation goes now: Outer loop= O(n) Middle loop=O(n(n+1)/2-1)=O(n^2) Innermost loop=O(n) Since O(f)*O(g)*O(h)=O(f*g*h) This will fetch me O(n^4).